# SML - Can't find where "uncaught exception Empty" is thrown in quicksort algorithm

Tags: exception, sml

I am trying to write a quicksort algorithm without using any List.nth functions. I've come up with this but when I try to test it, it ends up throwing an "uncaught exception Empty". I can't seem to find where this exception is thrown.
Here is my code:

```
(*returns last element in list*)
fun last (h::nil) = h
  | last (h::lst) = last(lst)
  | last _        = ~1;

(*returns middle element in list*)
fun middle (lst) = 
  let
    fun middle_rec (_ :: [])      (x :: _)  = x
      | middle_rec (_ :: _ :: []) (x :: _)  = x
      | middle_rec (_ :: _ :: xs) (_ :: ys) = middle_rec xs ys
      | middle_rec _              _         = ~1
    in
      middle_rec lst lst
    end;

(*return median of three elements*)
fun median(a,b,c) = 
  if ((b>a andalso a>c) orelse (c>a andalso a>b)) then a
  else if ((a>b andalso b>c) orelse (c>b andalso b>a)) then b
  else if ((a>c andalso c>b) orelse (b>c andalso c>a)) then c
  else ~1;

(*partitions a list with one containing elements smaller than or equal to p and one with elements greater than p*)
fun partition([], p) = ([], [])
  | partition(lst, p) =
      let
        fun part_rec ([], x::xs, y::ys, p) = (x::xs, y::ys)
          | part_rec (lst, x, y, p) =
              if hd(lst) <= p then part_rec(tl(lst), hd(lst)::x, y, p)
              else part_rec(tl(lst), x, hd(lst)::y, p)
      in
        part_rec(lst,[],[],p)
      end;

(*quicksort function*)
fun quicksort [] = []
  | quicksort(x::xs) = 
      let 
        val (left, right) = partition(x::xs, median(x, middle(x::xs), last(x::xs)))
      in
        quicksort left @ [x] @ quicksort right
      end;

quicksort([9, 4, 7, 2, 8, 5, 1, 6, 4, 3]);
```

Comment: You don't use `List.nth` anywhere in the example you provide, so its hard to say what specific issue you might have in using it. It would probably also help to read [the documentation](https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/list.html) for functions you're using if you don't know what exceptions they can raise.

Comment: Sorry, I have a typo in my original post. I'm trying not to use any List.nth in the code

Comment: Use small and systematic test cases, not large and arbitrary ones. Test each function in isolation. Your code works with `[]` but fails with `[1]`, and that is small enough for some investigation. Following along in the code, `partition ([1], 1)` has the same problem. Looking closer at `part_rec`, you might notice that `lst` could be empty.

Comment: Note that this is not *the* quicksort, which is an in-place algorithm that uses only a constant amount of extra space and requires constant-time element access.

Comment: You also have a bug where you include `x` in the partitioning - so it is in one of `left` and `right` - and then also insert it in the middle. Also, it is not your pivot element.

Answer (score 0):

Let's step through a very simple data set:

```
quicksort([1]);
val (left, right) = partition([1], median(1, middle([1]), last([1])))
val (left, right) = partition([1], median(1, 1, 1))
val (left, right) = partition([1], ~1)
val (left, right) = part_rec([1], [], [], ~1)
val (left, right) = part_rec([], [], [1], ~1)
```

And here we have a problem.

```
        fun part_rec ([], x::xs, y::ys, p) = (x::xs, y::ys)
          | part_rec (lst, x, y, p) =
              if hd(lst) <= p then part_rec(tl(lst), hd(lst)::x, y, p)
              else part_rec(tl(lst), x, hd(lst)::y, p)
```

The first pattern cannot apply, because the second argument is an empty list and thus cannot match with `x::xs`, so the second pattern must be applied. However, that means calling `hd` on an empty list, which will raise the `Empty` exception.